# É errado usar mais de um <thead>, <tbody> ou <tfoot> numa tabela?

Tags: html, html5, w3c-validador

Eu tenho uma tabela que recebe uma determinada formatação quando os elementos possuem um `tbody`. Por conta dessa formatação, pensei em usar o `tbody` duas vezes na mesma tabela, porém fiquei me questionando se isso seria válido.

Então, gostaria de tirar essa dúvida: Posso usar mais de um `tbody`, `tfoot` ou `thead` numa mesma tabela?

Por exemplo:

```html
<table class="table">
     <thead>
           <tr>
              <td colspan=2>
                 <h1>Título</h1>
             </td>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Nome</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Wallace</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No exemplo acima, seria inválido usar dois `thead`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<tbody>` pode sim, mas `<thead>` e `<tfoot>` [não é permitido pela especificação do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) (o mesmo valia para o [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1)).

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more colgroup elements, followed **optionally by a thead element, followed optionally by a tfoot element, followed by either zero or more tbody elements** or one or more tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot element (but there can only be one tfoot element child in total), optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

Ênfase minha no que é importante. A especificação é muito clara quando ela deixa ter mais de um. Quando ele usa o artigo *a* em inglês significa *um* mesmo, não mais que um.

## Possíveis soluções

Você pode juntar esses dois `<thead>`, já que não parece haver motivo para estar separado, ele pode ter mais que uma linha.

Poderia ser se tivesse agrupamentos, mas aí é o caso de ter uma tabela principal que contenha vários corpos e dentro dos corpos ter outras tabelas para cada grupo, aí em cada uma dessas tabelas secundárias você pode ter o cabeçalho e rodapé. Pode aninhar quantas tabelas quiser, em vários níveis.

Eventualmente poderá querer usar o [`<caption>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element) também para acrescentar alguma informação na tabela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

De acordo com o [DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_thead):

```
<!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
<!ELEMENT caption  %Inline;>
<!ELEMENT thead    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tfoot    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tbody    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT colgroup (col)*>
<!ELEMENT col      EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT tr       (th|td)+>
<!ELEMENT th       %Flow;>
<!ELEMENT td       %Flow;>
```

`(thead?) Aceito 0 ou 1 ocorrêcia`

`(tfoot?) Idem a anterior`

`(tbody+|tr+) Aceito 1 ou mais ocorrências`

Answer (score 8):

Usar mais de um `thead` e `tfoot` não são permitidos.  De acordo com [especificação do HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-table-element):

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more
>   colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, followed by
>   either zero or more tbody elements or one or more tr elements,
>   followed optionally by a tfoot element, optionally intermixed with one
>   or more script-supporting elements.

Ou seja:

Nesta ordem: opcionalmente um elemento de legenda, seguido por zero ou mais
`colgroup`, seguido opcionalmente por **um** elemento `thead`, seguido por
zero ou mais elementos `tbody` ou um ou mais elementos `tr`, seguidos opcionalmente por um elemento `tfoot`, opcionalmente misturados com um ou mais elementos de suporte de script.